# What is wrong with my laptop?

Tags: boot, laptop, troubleshooting

My laptop doesn't turn on. I cannot hear the hard drive spinning or the CPU cooler fan, and the LED is normally on when I push the power button. Also the charging LED turns on when I insert the charger, but the laptop doesn't work.

Comment: For someone to answer this question, please add more details, change the question title, make it more understandable, add more tags.

Comment: Take it to a repair shop for a proper diagnosis.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1524434/edit) your question and add info about your laptop's vendor and model.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop won't power on even when it's plugged in, it could have a faulty power adapter, battery, motherboard, graphics card or RAM. Remove the battery from the laptop and try powering it on with just the power adapter connected. If the laptop turns on without the battery, replace the battery. If the laptop turns on without the power adapter, replace the power adapter. If the laptop turns on but still doesn't boot past the login screen, take a photo of any unusual boot messages you get for the purpose of troubleshooting possible hardware problems.